# Problems with KHB method for assessing mediation in nested logit models

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, mediation

I have a binary outcome Y, a key independent variable X and a possible mediator Z, plus a control variable C.

In my original analysis I ran a "restricted" logit model of Y controlling for X and C, and then another "full" logit model that controls for X, C and Z. I interpreted the change in the coefficient for X between the two models as the  extent to which the effect of X is mediated by Z. Then, to illustrate the magnitude of the effects of X and Z I used the "full" model to calculate Pr(Y=1) for different values of X and Z, holding C at a constant value.

I now [know](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0081175012444861?casa_token=vMHyIONwvrIAAAAA%3A5WBSSvHIDhm7NaBNO56fV2gIGJXZ5R9DIqx47XZMcx3-unZsjj33cxk2jBYh7I5CFAYqkNdqBx08) that the first part of this approach is flawed: logit coefficients from nested models can't be directly compared, because they are on different scales, due to their different estimates of the variance of the latent “propensity” variable y*. So I downloaded the "KHB" ado file for Stata based on the method discussed in the paper I linked to above. This command calculates new versions of the "restricted" and "full" models that both use the “full” model’s estimate of y*’s variance so the coefficients can be directly compared. That all makes sense to me. But I ran into two problems.

Firstly, the KHB command gives substantially different answers for the “full” model (both in terms of coefficients and z/p values) than when I run the “full” model using the normal “logit” command in Stata. For example, the coefficient for X is 4.7 with a z value of 4.03 in the KHB version of the “full” model but it's 4.2 with a z value of 2.77 when I run it using a normal logit. In my understanding of the KHB procedure it shouldn’t do anything to the “full” model - the only changes are to the “restricted model.” So why is there a difference? These changes seem too big to merely be due to differences in estimation methods.

Second, there doesn’t seem to be a way to use “margins”  or other post-estimation commands on the models produced by the KHB command. So even if I knew that the KHB version of the “full” model is “better” or more comparable in some way than the basic logit model, there is no way to use it to created predicted probabilities.

The work-around I’m contemplating right now is to compare the coefficients from the KHB command’s version of the “restricted” model and the naïve logit version of the “full” model, and use the latter for predicted probabilities, but I want to make sure I’m not misunderstanding something.

Comment: Possibly sending you on a different track, but have you considered estimating this as a path model? Stata's gsem is designed for these types of analyses.